# Is there a way to completely stop all calculations on a thread?

Tags: fortran, openmp

Explanation of code and approach:

There are various mathematical methods (fortran subroutines) to solve a variable y, each method is sequential and runs on a single thread.  The speed of each methods solution is dependent on unknown conditions (i.e. it is a no free lunch situation and I do not know which method is fastest).  Therefor, the approach is to run each method on a separate thread, and once a method has found the solution, calculations on the other threads should stop (as they are required for operations after the `parallel sections` region)

```
!$omp parallel sections lastprivate(x, y)
    !$omp section
        call method_1_for_solving_y(x)
        !$omp cancel sections
    !$omp section
        call method_2_for_solving_y(x)
        !$omp cancel sections
    . . .
    !$omp section
        call method_z_for_solving_y(x)
        !$omp cancel sections
!$omp end parallel sections
```

The question:

The `!$omp cancel sections` construct does not completely cancel all operations on the threads that have not found the solution yet, is there a way to completely stop calculations on those threads?

Any additional advice, or possible other approaches would be appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: I think this differs by compiler. I found that for a good compiler (such as Intel; definitely not GCC) a cancel *very* quickly kills other taks. (Sorry, only done this with tasks, not sections.)

Comment: The check for a cancel only happens at certain limited points - see https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu101.html If you have no openmp directives in your called routines the cancel won't happen until they exit and hit the `$omp cancel sections`. You might consider putting a few `!$omp cancellation point sections` in your routines to encourage detecting the cancellation as early as possible. However *caveat emptor* I have never used this myself

Comment: If you want it killed during a call to some subroutine you don't want to mess with that might be difficult. I suppose the best approach might depend on the use case, does solving for `y` take a long amount of time?

Comment: @IanBush thank you for answering, the problem is placing cancellation points in a subroutine that is called to in the section scope is difficult, as Qubit mentioned. Nonetheless this looks like the most effective route with regards to speeding up my program.

Comment: @Qubit thank you for answering, yes solving `y` can take a long time. It seems like creating some _obscure_ code to detect the cancellation in the subroutines is the only solution to speeding up the program.

Comment: If it takes very long then perhaps you could also spawn separate processes, that may potentially be simpler to implement (although relatively in some regard). Nevertheless, killing off processes is trivial.